# Is RecyclerView Adapter destroyed in configuration change?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to know what happens to RecyclerView Adapter during configuration changes: does it get destroyed and so also all variables stored in it? I'm creating a form list with RecyclerView and I want to know if I can save the data of form in recycler adapter or I have to use view model for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Adapter isn't destroyed during config changes.

But usually it 'lives' on UI level, adapter reference is holded by activity or fragment. You may make adapter as singleton, but it seems to be a bad idea.

Keep data in viewmodel (or presenter), and send it to ui (and adapter) after configuration changed